# Django Oscar payment method errors when setting up

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-oscar

I've been having problems setting up the payment methods that can be used with Django Oscar.

I've tried using `django-oscar-datacash` and `django-paymentexpress`. The problem is, everytime I try to migrate, it's been saying that there is not module named `south`. However, when I installed `south` and migrated, what happened was it said that `south` doesn't exist in the database. I've read about `south` being removed from the current versions, so I tried rolling my Django back to version 1.7. When I tried to migrate, it threw and `HTMLParserError` which was fixed in the latest Django versions that are not compatible with `south` anymore.

How do I properly setup payment methods in Django Oscar? Aren't there any new libraries since the ones that I saw were modified 3-5 years ago. I also tried `django-oscar-paypal` but when I migrate, nothing is migrating and that the documentation is kind of confusing. Is there any way around this issue?